Dual British-Italian citizen, what passport should I use travelling to Italy on holiday?
I am an Italian citizen by birth and hold an Italian passport; in 2015 I moved to the UK using said passport, and I recently acquired British citizenship (both Italy and the UK allow dual citizenship) and hold a British passport as well.
I am due to travel to Italy in August for a week, and in September for two weeks and I haven't checked in yet with the airlines.
Which passport should I travel with?

Travelling with my British passport means I don't have to worry about being questioned when re-entering the UK, but it also means being unable to prove in Italy that I am a citizen, and risk being questioned by the authorities (a small chance of that happening, but I have seen it happen multiple times nonetheless). Both trips are road trips, where the chances of being stopped and searched are quite high.
Travelling with my Italian passport means I don't have to worry about being questioned in Italy but I'm afraid I will be denied re-entry, as I don't think I can use my Italian passport anymore to prove that I have the right to live in the UK (gaining British citizenship means I have lost my EU settled status, which was linked to my Italian passport).
Travelling with both solves the above issues, but it means that I'm at risk of losing both passports at the same time. If I do lose them while in Italy, I cannot ask for help at the British Embassy in Italy; quoting the gov.uk website:


As a dual national you cannot get diplomatic help from the British government when you are in the other country where you hold citizenship.1

Getting a replacement Italian passport while travelling in Italy is a proper pain but it's doable, and I actually had to do so when I lost it travelling there in 2022 (but I was not a British citizen yet). It would also mean having the same issue re-entering the UK, as I cannot prove I have the right to live in the UK.
Are my worries well-founded, or am I just being paranoid?
EDIT: as suggested by the accepted answer, an Italian ID card can be used as proof of citizenship while in Italy. I will then travel on my British passport and with my Italian ID on me, while leaving the Italian passport at home here in the UK. Something that I did forget to mention, in Italy there is the obbligation to carry a form of ID with you at all times (art. 294 reg es. TULPS), and show it upon request from any law enforcement authority. Since a British driving licence might not be recognised as a form of ID (there have been issues in the past where even an Italian licence would not be a valid form of ID), that would have left me with the only option of carrying my passport with me at all times, hence increasing the risk of losing it.
Adding to this hurdle is the fact that, upon stopping, I also need to prove that I am legally in the country; a Schengen or EU citizen won't have this issue of course, and all they have to do is showing a Schengen/EU ID or passport, but the UK is neither in the EU nor in the Schengen area. I've seen a dual Moroccan/Italian citizen been brought to the police station for questioning, even after showing his Italian ID as proof of citizenship, just because he had a non-Italian sounding name, and that's just to mention one of the multiple power trip instances I have witnessed myself. So while I might be a bit paranoid, I have also seen things from the Italian authorities that just reinforce my paranoia.

If I do lose them while in Italy, I cannot ask for help at the British Embassy in Italy This means that the embassy cannot provide 'consular assistance' like being visited by a consular official if you're arrested. It does not mean they won't help you get a new passport.

@MJeffryes ah that's good to hear. I know you can request for an emergency passport while abroad, but I thought that sentence barring diplomatic help would also include getting a replacement passport while in my other home country. Would you please have any link to support that? I did search for that, but could not find anything at all.

There are millions of dual national UK citizens. After the UK, the country they are most likely to be applying for a passport in is the country of their other citizenship. There is absolutely no bar on this. Otherwise how on Earth would they be able to travel to the UK? The fact you have found nothing about this specifically not being allowed should make it clear that it is.

Any passport will work for any border crossing. Your best choice is to use the Italian passport to enter and exit Italy and the UK one to exit and reenter the UK. a) you carry back up, b) this gets your through immigration the fastest

Not adding a new answer just to add this point but the consular assistance rules are strictly based on your citizenship. It doesn't matter whether you hold or bear an Italian document of any kind or whether you used it to enter the country, as long as you are an Italian citizen, Italy can use that to deny access to you to the British consulate (e.g. in detention, which is mostly what this is about).

You want British consular help in your own country? I did not know Italy has fallen so far down. Why has the EU not kicked Italy out? :)

@stackoverblown we're still waiting in line behind hungary and a few other countries. we're not far from it, but definitely not the first :D

"As a dual national you cannot get diplomatic help from the British government when you are in the other country where you hold citizenship": this means that if you get arrested you are not entitled to UK consular assistance as a matter of right (but Italy might allow it as a courtesy).  It does not mean that you cannot obtain a UK passport in Italy, nor that you cannot avail yourself of other UK consular services.


I am due to travel to Italy in August for a week, and in September for two weeks and I haven't checked in yet with the airlines.

To enter the Schengen Area, EU citizens are only required to prove that they are EU citizens.
Therefore an Italian ID card can also be used.
If you don't have one you can apply for one at the responsible consulate in the United Kingdom.


Schengen Border Code
Article 8 (Border checks on persons)
...
2. On entry and on exit, persons enjoying the right of free movement under Union law shall be subject to the following checks:
(a) verification of the identity and the nationality of the person and of the authenticity and validity of the travel document for crossing the border, including by consulting the relevant databases, in particular:
...

The Annex of the European Agreement on Regulations governing the Movement of Persons between Member States of the Council of Europe from 1957-12-13 list which documents are accepted and was last updated in 2016.

Sources:

Electronic Id Card – Consolato Generale d'Italia Londra


Funny enough, I already have an appointment in June at the Italian Consulate to get a new electronic ID card. I still have the old paper one and, while still valid, I can't use it for some government electronic services and I'm afraid it won't be recognised anymore outside of Italy. Travelling with my ID while there would be my preferred choice, as it is less of a pain to get a new one, and I can easily get a replacement while in Italy in a couple of hours if I were to lose it. I had no idea it could be used as proof of citizenship, but the more you know.

You can use it to travel the whole of the EU and Schengen, and even some countries outside that area.

@vale.maio2 Bringing your British passport PLUS Italian paper ID is perfectly fine

My recent experience in France and Germany is that an ID card is no longer sufficient to enter the Schengen Area. I usually travel with a UK passport and French ID card, and used to enter the Schengen Area showing only my ID card, but the last few times I’ve also had to show my passport. (The rules still say that an ID card is sufficient, but I try not to argue with border police.) Of course all this isn’t an issue for the OP since they’ll have a passport anyway.

@StephenKitt A valid national identity card (in some cases even a recently expired passport) have been common place since 1957. The Annex of European Agreement on Regulations governing the Movement of Persons between Member States of the Council of Europe from 1957-12-13 list which documents are accepted and was last updated in 2016.

@MarkJohnson Clearly, reiterating the rules isn't a cogent response to a comment that reads “the rules still say that an ID card is sufficient”.

@StephenKitt: Could you explain where you were stopped and by whom? Was it UK Border Control in UK?

@Relaxed It is, however, an appropriate comment to the false claim 'that an ID card is no longer sufficient to enter the Schengen Area' since it has been so since 1957 as well as Article 8 (2)(a) of the Schengen Border Code (which the border guards know very well).

@MarkJohnson No, it's not. The whole claim that you failed to properly quote was “My recent experience in France and Germany […] the last few times I’ve also had to show my passport“. The point always was about the gap between the rules and the power relationship you face at the border. Pretending it's not happening because the rules haven't changed isn't useful (as if the OP didn't know that) and calling it a false claim is disrespectful.

@MarkJohnson it was at the border in France and Germany (travelling to and from the UK); French and German border police asked to see my passport when I gave them my ID card. I’m not claiming that the rules have changed, but that the border police don’t necessarily follow them (and I haven’t tried arguing the point with them). When entering the UK I always give the UK border police my UK passport.

@StephenKitt There are probably tens of thousands French citizens crossing over to Germany daily. 99% of them won't have a passport to show with them (why should they? none is required). And based on this you are claiming 'that an ID card is no longer sufficient to enter the Schengen Area.'? This may come as a great shock to you, but France and Germany (togeather with the Benelux countries) were the founding members of the Schengen Area. This has absolutely nothing to do with entering the Schengen Area.

@MarkJohnson “travelling to and from the UK”. I’m well aware of how Schengen works; when travelling between France and Germany I typically don’t even need to show ID.

@StephenKitt: Just to be clear: French and German border police on the way into Schengen, not on the way out? That's strange.

@MatthieuM. yes, on the way in, and I was surprised as well!

MarkJohnson It was between the UK and either France or Germany. Indeed, travel between France and Germany has absolutely nothing to do with entering the Schengen area but you are the only one who was confused about that so highlighting it is unnecessary. Of course, it was completely obvious since @StephenKitt's first comment but if you have trouble reading English, maybe just assume he knows what he is talking about and let that guide your interpretation instead of trying to lecture him on what did or did not happen?

@StephenKitt for what it's worth, that isn't an EU-wide thing. I regularly enter and leave Shengen (Greece) with my Greek ID card (last time was a couple of weeks ago and I was flying in from a non-Shengen country). So it might just be the specific countries you mentioned or even the specific guards you ran into. Or you just look dodgy ;)

@terdon most likely the latter! More seriously, I imagine it’s the specific guards, yes.

@StephenKitt Damn, wonder how they'd deal with me as I only have an EU ID card (being eligible to enter the UK on it). They can't send me back to the UK, that's for sure. FWIW I fly basically every week and never had issues entering Schengen so far.

@Crazydre I’m just explaining what happened to me, not saying that that happens to everyone. If I was asked for a passport in your situation I would argue with the border police; since I have a passport it wasn’t worth it.

Travel with both:

At check-in/gate UK-Italy, present the Italian passport or ID
At Italian entry border control, present the Italian passport or ID
At check-in/gate Italy-UK, present the British passport
At Italian exit border control, present the Italian passport or ID
At UK border control, present the British passport.


That's the correct answer. Anything else would work to, but this gets your through immigration the fastest.

It is also what I already wrote, if in different wording.

@Willeke No it isn't. Your answer advises that it makes no difference which passport you use, while this answer is specific about what passport you should use in a given scenario.

I tell that you should use the passports this way but that you do not need to worry if you lost one, as you can travel on both, answering OP's worries as well.

At check-in don't you have to present the passport that you have booked the tickets on? I'm assuming this will be booked as return flight, not two singles (where you can use both passports).  That is what will be used by the airport system to get through security area. That might be a seperate system to immigration checks though so maybe different passport can be used then.

@HSharp My observations are that (a) most people now check-in online; (b) the airline staff want to be sure that you are the passenger on the ticket and that you can enter at the destination, but are less worried about the nationality on the physical passport matching the nationality used for booking; (c) border control officials want to see you are allowed to enter and will not overstay / have not overstayed.  This answer is most likely to keep everyone satisfied.

@HSharp I've never had my passport number compared to the one on check-in (or to the one on my residence permit), I just grab whichever is easier to hand over when they're checking my eligibility to enter the country at the gate. IME they mostly check validity (both in terms of start/end dates, expiry dates, and validity to enter the country on the receiving end, sometimes I've also seen them count days on schengen stamps on non-residents), that the name matches the ticket, and the face matches you. Some airlines may be more vigilant of course.

@HSharp "don't you have to present the passport that you have booked the tickets on?": No.  Anyone, even a citizen of a single country, might have replaced their passport between the booking and the flight, for any of a number of reasons including loss or expiration.  But further than that I always check in with my EU passport when flying to the EU or the Schengen area and my US passport when flying to the US, and most of my flying is on round-trip bookings between the Schengen area and the US, and not only has it never been a problem but nobody has ever even said anything about it.

@phoog Depends on the airline: with easyJet, Ryanair or WIZZ, if you don't present the EXACT document you specify in the booking, you can be denied boarding if the staff notices (which they rarely do)

@Crazydre in my recent experience of several easyJet flights, the only check on the passport is visual, at the gate, against the boarding pass which doesn't show the document number or nationality.  I think I saw someone using a Schengen residence permit on an intra-Schengen easyJet flight recently, which certainly isn't the passport used to book the ticket, but I don't remember for sure.

@phoog Well you don't provide travel document info for easyjet intra-Schengen flights

You are worrying too much.
It is rather unlikely to lose a passport and in any case your Italian passport would allow you entry into the UK, you will not even get a stamp. Only if you are asked how long you are going to stay you will have to explain why you use the Italian rather than the UK passport.
Same with the UK passport in Italy other than you would get a stamp unless you can prove you are Italian.
Show the airline (or ferry company) the passport of the country you are heading to, and the passport officers the passport of their country (or the Italian one if another Schengen country.)

It is rather unlikely to lose a passport
Ha! As my mother says, I'd be losing my head if I didn't have a neck... I just don't want to take any chances with Italian authorities, not at the port of entry but at random checkpoints during the trip. I have see my fair share of authorities on a power trip there, taking in for questioning people who could not prove being a Schengen citizen.

@vale.maio2 get an ID card for this. Much easier to carry than a passport.

Keep your passport separate. I've never lost a passport in fifty years of travelling. The chances that you lose both is tiny.

I think this answer understates the problem. E.g. if you enter Italy on your British passport and get a stamp, you are then expected to get an exit stamp on your way out and not exceed 90 days in a 180 day period. While ultimately that can all be resolved by establishing that you are a citizen, it can also create unnecessary hassle in the future (e.g. having to explain what looks on paper to be an overstay). So yes, it is possible to do what you are suggesting, but it's best avoided unless you have no choice (e.g. your other passport has been lost).

True, only do it if necessary but it is possible.

@vale.maio2: I generally travel with both ID card and Passport (in EU). My goto setup is to have my ID on me (fits within my wallet easily) and my Passport in my carry-on luggage (which I leave in the hotel/residence). The idea is that even if I lose my wallet (or it gets stolen) and thus lose my ID, then I still have my Passport to fall back on. I similarly have a "fall back" credit/debit card in my carry-on for the same purpose. Don't put all your eggs in the same basket, that's all.

@vale.maio2 one helpful thing in case you lose one or the other, getting a police report might make it easier to both get a new document (especially emergency passports require it) and help you have an easier time explaining your situation at the border (why you're leaving italy with a british passport without an entry stamp, why you're entering uk with an italian passport as a uk citizen, etc).

Ad an addition to other answers (so maybe your question was too broad/you asked too many questions, which it is not good for this website design).
If you are Italian, you can always enter in Italy, and if you are British citizen the same apply to UK, so you have not such risk (but without valid documents things may be slow because they should be sure you are a citizen). So do not worry about deny reentry. So part of your worries are non-existent.
I think you also misquoted the UK site, or better: you misinterpreted it. You can always go to a British consular office to ask help about documents (get British documents), or also to vote. So you can ask to replace your passport without problems. What you quoted is not about that.
The quote is about diplomatic help (not consular help), which it is different: if you get arrested, usually you can ask your embassy for help (often it means translations, legal help for first steps, etc.), IIRC this is required by some of the Vienna conventions (or maybe an other basic international treaty about embassies). But if you are also a citizen of local territory, local nationality has priority: they just reinforce what was in past common sense: you are not a foreigner to local laws. Also diplomatic help may occur for evacuations (wars, disasters), etc. I think the meaning of such quotation is about that (and newspapers give me think a lot of people thinks about embassies have free from jail cards).

The gist of the answer is not wrong but I don't think “diplomatic help” and “consular help“ are really different well-defined concepts. The definition of consular functions in the relevant Vienna Convention uses the verb “assist” and in other contexts this is also called “consular assistance“.

@Relaxed furthermore, the "relevant Vienna convention" in this case is the one on consular relations, not the one on diplomatic relations.  So the original UK text is using "diplomatic" very loosely indeed.
